# simple memory malloc and free in ip_output.c of linux kernel

Tags: c, linux, kernel

I am doing a very simple operation at the method of ip_queue_xmit in ip_output.c of ipv4 stack in linux kernel 3.12.

The code is very simple.

```
char *p = kmalloc(48, GFP_KERNEL);
kfree(p);
```

This will be called every time this method is called.

But the result is that the whole system is not responsive at all. This is a very simple, not sure what I am doing wrong. Can anybody help?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Shot in the dark. Don't use the GFP_KERNEL flag, you are probably in the middle of some critical code holding a spin lock or something. Try GFP_ATOMIC.

You have to remember, in kernel land there are many things that you in can do only under the right circumstances.

Also, the allocation might fail. Check the pointer before using it or freeing it.